# How to take a photo and measure pixels of a specific color?

Tags: image, arduino, pixel

I am a PhD student in the Faculty of Agriculture in Turkey. We have to measure the leaf area of some plants in our studies. I have used a method that gives almost realistic results.

I cut off leaves from plants and put them on an A4 sheet of paper so that they don't touch each other. Then, I take pictures vertically of the A4 paper with leaves. Later, I get the pictures to Photoshop. I select the leaves with the color range tool and check the pixel numbers of leaves from the histogram. So I have an A4 paper's real size and pixel number, and I have the leaves pixel numbers. I can calculate a realistic leaf area by using these components.

So this manual method is more effective than old methods, but if you have to measure a lot of samples, it takes a lot of time. I need to make my own Arduino-based device and it has to take pictures and analyse leaf area with the pixel-counting method as I explained above.

Is it possible to do it with Arduino? Any idea will be beneficial for me.

Best regards.

Comment: A standard smart phone with a camera would be capable of this and likely easier to develop.

Comment: Did you do any sanity check like how big of an image can you put in Arduino's memory?

Comment: I would recommend going for a Raspberry pi + OpenCV instead of an Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a Raspberry Pi and a Pi camera to capture the image and then using Python and Python libraries like Numpy, pandas, and OpenCV ( open source image processing library) you can perform the task.

It is easier to capture the image and store it on the server and then easily retrieve it and perform the process.( using raspberry pi)

But if you still want to use Arduino for this then You will have to use a camera shield and then use Python for the process( but i recommend you to use raspberry pi and a pi camera)